# Github Private repo access

Tags: github, repository, private, collaboration

I took a coding test and pushed the code in my private repo to be checked by the test taker company.
I was given a username to send a collaboration invite so that the user can check the code.
The invite is still pending and has not been accepted by the user but they are claiming that they have indeed checked and I failed the test.
How can anyone access my private repo without even accepting the invite.

This may sound a bit silly but is it possible that an AI app can access my private repo and the status has not been updated on my repo about the invite. Just thinking of all possibilities before raising it.
Please let me know if its at all possible to access any private repo without accepting the invite as the invite still shows pending status.

Thanks